# Getting error C2248 when trying to access protected constructors from a base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, protected

In Stroustrup's *Programming: Principals and Practice using C++* he has a wrapper for a graphics library (FLTK), which has the following definition for a base class:

```
class Shape  {  
protected:
Shape() { }
Shape(initializer_list<Point> lst);

//more irrelevant code below
}
```

And a derived class

```
struct Open_polyline : Shape {  
public:
using Shape::Shape;

//more irrelevant code here
}
```

When I try to use the Open_polyline's supposedly inherited constructors like this:

```
Open_polyline opl{ {100,100}, {150,150},{200,200},{250,250} };
```

I get the compiler error C2248 stating that

"Graph_lib::Open_polyline::Open_polyline': cannot access protected member declared in class 'Graph_lib::Open_polyline"

I read up online about the 'using' keyword and thought that it may be causeing problems by making Open_polyline's constructors protected as well, so I edited Open_polyline's definition to be:

```
struct Open_polyline : Shape {  
public:
Open_polyline() {};
Open_polyline(initializer_list<Point> lst) : Shape(lst) {};

}
```

But I still get the same error message. How can I used the protected base class's constructors?

Answer (score 1):

From [this inheriting constructors reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#Inheriting_constructors):

> If overload resolution selects an inherited constructor, it is accessible if it would be accessible when used to construct an object of the corresponding base class: ***the accessibility of the using-declaration that introduced it is ignored***.

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

For other members (functions, variables) it works as you intent, but not for constructors.

---

The problem with your second example is that you don't have a default constructor for the `Shape` base class. That means you can't default-construct the `Open_polyline` class either (as that implicitly needs to be able to default-constructor the base `Shape` class).

You solve this by adding a default constructor to the `Shape` class. Or by removing the `Open_polyline` default constructor.

Comment: So, how are protected base class constructors used for an instantiation of derived class's objects?

Comment: "Your second example should work fine, even with the private inheritance." . It gives the same error.

Comment: @steve It shouldn't give the *same* error, but a totally different one. Updated my answer with this problem.

Answer (score -1):

You used private inheritance. Try to write this

```
struct Open_polyline : public Shape { ...
```