# The using-declaration for inheriting constructors

Tags: c++, inheritance, using-declaration

I'm strugling to understand why I'm getting a compilation error in the example below:

```
class Shape
{
protected:
    Shape() : num(0) {}
    Shape(int i) : num(i) {}
public:
    int getNum() const { return num; }
private:
    int num;
};

struct Lines : Shape
{
    using Shape::Shape;
};

int main()
{
    Lines l; // OK
    Lines l2(10); // error here
}
```

E0330   "Lines::Shape(int i)" (declared implicitly) is inaccessible
C2248   'Lines::Lines': cannot access protected member declared in class 'Lines'

The actual code of this problem is from the book "“Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++, 2nd Edition” by B.Stroustrup:

```
struct Open_polyline : Shape { // open sequence of lines
    using Shape::Shape; // use Shape’s constructors (§A.16)
    void add(Point p) { Shape::add(p); }
};

class Shape { // deals with color and style and holds sequence of lines
public:
    void draw() const; // deal with color and draw lines
    virtual void move(int dx, int dy); // move the shape +=dx and +=dy
    void set_color(Color col);
    Color color() const;
    void set_style(Line_style sty);
    Line_style style() const;
    void set_fill_color(Color col);
    Color fill_color() const;
    Point point(int i) const; // read-only access to points
    int number_of_points() const;
    Shape(const Shape&) = delete; // prevent copying
    Shape& operator=(const Shape&) = delete;
    virtual ~Shape() { }
protected:
    Shape() { }
    Shape(initializer_list<Point> lst); // add() the Points to this Shape
    virtual void draw_lines() const; // draw the appropriate lines
    void add(Point p); // add p to points
    void set_point(int i, Point p); // points[i]=p;
private:
    vector<Point> points; // not used by all shapes
    Color lcolor {fl_color()}; // color for lines and characters (with default)
    Line_style ls {0};
    Color fcolor {Color::invisible}; // fill color
};

Open_polyline opl = {
    {100,100}, {150,200}, {250,250}, {300,200}
};
```

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: Inherited constructors keep the same access regardless of were the using declaration is.

Comment: It's maybe not that surprising that the `using Shape::Shape;` declaration preserves the original access specification of `Shape(int)`, making it `protected` not `public`. But then why is the `Lines` default constructor accessible?

Comment: @NathanPierson No constructor was specified, so the compiler provides `Lines` a default constructor like always.

Comment: @NathanOliver I guess `using Shape::Shape;` won't replace the default-generated default constructor with a `protected` one just because `Shape` has a protected default constructor. Peculiar.

Comment: @NathanPierson The rule for the default constructor generation is *If no user-declared constructors of any kind are provided for a class type (struct, class, or union), the compiler will always declare a default constructor as an inline public member of its class.*.  `using Shape::Shape;` is not a user declared constructor.

Comment: @NathanOliver I guess this is what happens, but I’m confused because this example is from the book “Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++, 2nd Edition” by B.Stroustrup.

Comment: He's had wrong code before.  I didn't see anything on the eratta.  Can you give more context, I do not have the book.  Do they say that this code should compile?

Comment: It's from chapter 13. Graphics Classes. The actual comment on this code is "The declaration using Shape::Shape is a using declaration. It says that an Open_polyline (I named it Lines above) can use the constructors defined for Shape. Shape has a default constructor (§9.7.3) and an initializer-list constructor (§18.2), so the using
declaration is simply a shorthand for defining those two constructors for Open_polyline."

Comment: As far as I can tell Stroustrup got this wrong. I found this Q back from 2019 that has the same answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55534319/getting-error-c2248-when-trying-to-access-protected-constructors-from-a-base-cla

Comment: There might have been a defect report where this was legal, or at least it wasn't well specified, but has since ben patched.

Comment: @NathanOliver Anyway, thanks for your reply, it really helped clarify this case for me.